# d3.js can't access previous data attrTween

Tags: javascript, layout, d3.js, pie-chart

I have a pie chart that is properly displaying. I mutate the underlying data (successfully) and then try too animate the pie chart slices to their new sizes. Without using any sort of tween or transition, the slices re-size fine (although instantly). I've tried to use example code to add smooth transitions but I'm having trouble making them work. My current updateData method looks like this.

```
var changeData = function() {
                arcs.data(pie(data[1].semdata), key)
                .select("path")
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attrTween("d", arcTween);
```

I'm confused about how to write the tween method. I set up my arcTween method as follows to help my diagnose the problem.

```
function arcTween(var1, var2, var3) {
    console.log(var1);
    console.log(var2);
    console.log(var3);
    console.log(this);
```

- var1 ends up being the updated d3 pie slice object (startAngle, endAngle, value)
- var2 ends up being an index
- var3 ends up being the updated d value of the path DOM element
- "this" ends up being the updated path DOM element

With those arguments all ending up as being related to the updated data, how can I do interpolation without having a way to know what the original data's start/end angles were before the update?

Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var margin = {top:20, right:20, bottom:20, left:20};
        var w = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
        var h = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var outerRadius = w / 2;
        var innerRadius = 0;

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(innerRadius)
            .outerRadius(outerRadius);

        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                        .value(function(d) {
                        return d.freq;
                        })
                        .sort(null);

        var chart = d3.select(".chart")
            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        d3.json("../data/2012_semesters_json.js", function(data) {

            var arcs = chart.selectAll("g.arc")
                .data(pie(data[0].semdata), key)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")");

            console.log(arcs);

            arcs.append("path")
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                    return color(i);
                })
                .attr("d", arc);

            arcs.append("text")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.data.term;
            });

            chart.selectAll("g.arc")
                .on("click", function(d) {
                    changeData();   
                    });

            var changeData = function() {
                arcs.data(pie(data[1].semdata), key)
                .select("path")
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attrTween("d", arcTween);

                arcs.select("text")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.data.term;
            });
                }

        });

        var key = function(d) {
            return d.data.term;
        }

        function arcTween(a) {
        console.log(this._current);
            var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
            this._current = i(0);
            return function(t) {
                return arc(i(t));
            };
        }


    </script>
```

And here's a snippet of what a json object looks like.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "course": "ACCT207",
    "semdata": [
            {"term": "2008 Fall", "freq": 35},
            {"term": "2009 Spring", "freq": 20},
            {"term": "2009 Fall", "freq": 225},
            {"term": "2010 Spring", "freq": 16},
            {"term": "2010 Fall", "freq": 6},
            {"term": "2011 Spring", "freq": 1},
            {"term": "2011 Fall", "freq": 30},
            {"term": "2012 Spring", "freq": 0}
            ]
}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410)?

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff, I've tried using Mike's code but I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'data' in undefined". If I try to call console.log(this._current), only "undefined" is logged because "this" refers to the actual path element in the DOM (which I assume does not have a ._current attribute. Is my function getting called from the correct place, what should this._current actually be?

Comment: Well this is the general approach that you'll have to follow. I can't really tell you anything further without seeing the code.

Comment: I've added my code to the original post @LarsKotthoff. Do any major errors jump out at you? I'm suspecting I'm performing my update selection improperly. Any insight would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: You're not saving the data in `this._current`.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, my data is being bound to the g DOM elements, not the actual path DOM elements?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63413/discussion-between-sean-lafferty-and-lars-kotthoff).

Comment: I have a similar issue and am wondering if this problem was ever resolved.